# How to execute a search template within Elasticsearch by using apache.httpcomponents.httpclient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, httpclient

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/contact/_search/template?pretty -d '{"id":"contact", "params": {"q": "123456", "company": "2"}}'
```

It works well, but how can I use httpclient to make this call?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it like this:

```
StringRequestEntity entity = new StringRequestEntity(
    "{\"id\":\"contact\", \"params\": {\"q\": \"123456\", \"company\": \"2\"}}",
    "application/json",
    "UTF-8");

PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://localhost:9200/contact/_search/template");
postMethod.addParameter("pretty", "");
postMethod.setRequestEntity(entity);
int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(post);
```

Comment: Your code came up with something wrong in my versioned httpclien, but I got some inspiration from them, thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I typed off my memory but haven't compiled. What was the error?

Comment: `HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);  httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString, Consts.UTF_8));
`